# How to change label text on mouseover in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-interface

In asp.net, when the user mouses over a button, I'd like to change the text of a label to explain what the button does.

Then when they mouse-out of the button, the label should go back to its default text.

What is the best way to achieve this?  Are there ASP.net controls for this?  Or should I just code custom javascript?

Comment: You should probably handle this purely in javascript.  The use of a library like jQuery will make such a task fairly trivial.

Comment: @KarmicCoder not only he should do it in javascript, I think it's **his only choice** unless he is looking to annoy the hell out of users by having postbacks all over the place.

Comment: @kaes - check Tooltip option else pure javascript is the option.

Comment: Javascript is the way to go.

jQuery would be too expensive if this is the only script requirement of the page

Comment: @iandayman, it would be expensive, but the mouse events aren't common across all event models, whereas they are in jQuery. To be fair though, this functionality won't be affected by these differences in a a big enough way to justify using jQuery.

Comment: many sites are using jquery now, so it wouldn't be expensive if they're already using it elsewhere.

Comment: UX is what it comes down to. UX can justify functionally detrimental code. You can always check out something like http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/demo.html if you want to get creative on stripping JavaScript. It can be dangerous if you plan to have dynamic page environments, but if you have a predictable usage and can test across multiple browsers, you are mostly "safe" to strip unnecessary JS (never recommended with Frameworks like jQuery, but if performance is really a concern, go for it).

Comment: Thanks all.  I'm going with JQuery client-side only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the label text using a little jQuery magic is really quite easy.

Here's what you'd use for your label

```
<label id="mylabel" 
       title="My Text" 
       data-replace="My NEW Text">My Text</label>
```

and here's what you'd use for your jQuery

```
$("#mylabel").mouseover(function () {
  $(this).text($(this).data('replace'));
});


$("#mylabel").mouseout(function () {
  $(this).text($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

You can [test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/x2eUZ/).

Also, **if** you're using web forms, you can either add the data attribute in your code behind or directly in the control. Doing it in the code behind is good for dynamic text.

```
mylabel.Attributes.Add("data-original", "My Text");
mylabel.Attributes.Add("data-replace", "My NEW Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit to answer your question]

```
<asp:label id="label1" class="hover" data-replace="The tooltip text #1" data-original="Original Value" runat="server">Original Value</asp:label>
```

Then:

```
$(".hover").hover(

function() {
    var text = $(this).attr("data-replace");
    $(this).text(text);
}, function() {
    var text = $(this).attr("data-original");
    $(this).text(text);
}
);
```

[Old post...oops, answered wrong question]

Using something like jQuery Tools Tooltip plugin is great for this stuff!

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Just add title attribute to your label and a little JavaScript:

```
<asp:label id="label1" title="The tooltip text #1" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

Then

```
$("#label1").tooltip();
```

Comment: Using a tooltip is a good option over changing the actual text of the label, however @kaes did ask to change the text of the label. You would be wise to give a jQuery example on how to do that as well in order to actually "answer" the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution , I hope it will helps you

```
   myItemLabel.ToolTip = "Text you want to show when hover";
```

Combine this with the jQuery Tooltip plugin (or similar) to get better effects.

```
     myItemLabel.CssClass = "has-tooltip";
```

Then in your mark up.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('.has-tooltip').tooltip();
      });
     </script>
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as @Watermark-Studios answer, unfortunately it doesn't actually answer how to change the label text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('.has-tooltip').tooltip();
   });
  </script>
```